# How do I make this loop break when the score counter reaches 5?

Tags: c#

I am in the process of writing a text-based Rock Paper Scissors in C#. I have a score counter for both the player and the AI-opponent respectively. In theory the main loop should break when either the player or the AI-opponent reaches a score of 5. The problem, however, is that the loop doesn't break. It just loops around, ignoring the directive to break once a score of 5 is reached.

I have tried moving the break statement along with it's "if" condition, and the rest of the code, around to different locations in the loop. I thought putting the break statement and its associated if statement above the main code would work, but it didn't.
I then placed the break statement inside of an 'if statement', whose condition was that the score had to be more than 5 in order for it to break the loop.
I then placed the main code inside of an 'else if' statement whose condition was that the score had to be lower than 5 in order for it to run.
I expected this to solve the problem, but it did not. The loop simply continued.

`

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
     class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();
        static string[] moves = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
        static string opMoves()
        {
            return moves[random.Next(0,2)];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables

            var names = new List<string> { "Hector Tucker", "Karen Adams", "Maxine Welch",
                        "May Ray", "Raymond Wood", "Leroy Newman", "Franklin Morrison",
                        "Bernice Warren", "Ron Smith", "Dave Evans", "Roosevelt Hodges",
                        "Moses James", "Noah Robertson", "Laverne Baldwin", "Leslie Tyler",
                        "Lillie Vasquez", "Tiffany Mann", "Jane Patrick", "Tracy Spencer",
                        "Kevin Wheeler"};



            int index = random.Next(0,names.Count);


            string namesIndex = names[index];

            // Booleans

            bool tied = true;
            bool playing = true;

            // Score

            int playerScore = 0;
            int opScore = 0;

            // Strings

            string winner = "No one";
            string opName = names[index];


            // Main Code

            Console.WriteLine("Time to play Rock, Paper, Scissors!");

            Console.WriteLine("Please write your name below:");

            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("User:  " + playerName);

            Console.WriteLine("Choosing opponent...");

            Console.WriteLine("Your opponent is " + opName);

            Console.WriteLine("Let's start!");

            while (playing)
            {
                if ((playerScore >= 5 || opScore >= 5) || (playerScore >= 5 && opScore >= 5))
                {
                    if (playerScore >= 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, ", playerName, "! You won!");
                    }
                    else if (opScore >= 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(opName, " won the game! Congratulations!");
                    }
                    playing = false;
                }

                else if ((playerScore < 5 || opScore < 5) || (playerScore < 5 && opScore < 5))
                {
                    string opMove = opMoves();
                    Console.WriteLine(playerScore);
                    Console.WriteLine(opScore);
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose your move! Valid moves:\nRock\nPaper\nScissors");
                    string playerMove = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine(namesIndex + " Choosing move...");
                    Console.WriteLine("Your move:  " + playerMove + "\n " + opName + "'s move:  " + opMove);


                    // If player uses paper and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper beats Rock! You gain 1 point!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses paper and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors beat Paper! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses paper and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper vs Paper is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper beats rock! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        opScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock vs Rock is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock beats Scissors! 1 point awarded to player!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors beat Paper! 1 point awarded to player!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock beats Scissors! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        opScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors vs Scissors is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Your code is quite long for this site. When asking a question, please make a copy of your project and remove as much code as possible. Remove as much Console output as possible, because the Console output is usually not the problem. Avoid user input as well and use hard coded values whenever possible. Doing so creates a [mre].

Comment: In your case, all the similar if-statements don't seem to be relevant, so you can remove them as well. Just ignore the rock-paper-scissors rules and give someone a point in a hardcoded way.

Comment: DEBUG! Put a breakpoint in your code and step through it, checking the flow and variable values.

Comment: It looks like the game stops playing after it reached the `playing = false;` instruction. Please check if you compiled the latest version of your code and you're not running an older copy. Please clarify what's wrong and what you expect.

Comment: Your main problem is probably Console output. It seems you're coming from Python where you do a `print(a,b,c)`. In C# concatenate the strings like `Console.WriteLine(a+b+c);`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Except that - as @ThomasWeller noted, the output when the game ends is not as you probably wanted it to be.

Comment: You might've misunderstood what the problem is. The loop doesn't break for me at all. That's the problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code. I changed only the if-statements for the checking score.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
     class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();
        static string[] moves = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
        static string opMoves()
        {
            return moves[random.Next(0,2)];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables

            var names = new List<string> { "Hector Tucker", "Karen Adams", "Maxine Welch",
                        "May Ray", "Raymond Wood", "Leroy Newman", "Franklin Morrison",
                        "Bernice Warren", "Ron Smith", "Dave Evans", "Roosevelt Hodges",
                        "Moses James", "Noah Robertson", "Laverne Baldwin", "Leslie Tyler",
                        "Lillie Vasquez", "Tiffany Mann", "Jane Patrick", "Tracy Spencer",
                        "Kevin Wheeler"};



            int index = random.Next(0,names.Count);


            string namesIndex = names[index];

            // Booleans

            bool tied = true;
            bool playing = true;

            // Score

            int playerScore = 0;
            int opScore = 0;

            // Strings

            string winner = "No one";
            string opName = names[index];


            // Main Code

            Console.WriteLine("Time to play Rock, Paper, Scissors!");

            Console.WriteLine("Please write your name below:");

            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("User:  " + playerName);

            Console.WriteLine("Choosing opponent...");

            Console.WriteLine("Your opponent is " + opName);

            Console.WriteLine("Let's start!");

            while (playing)
            {
                string gameoverText = string.Empty;

                if (playerScore >= 5)
                    gameoverText = $"Congratulations, {playerName}! You won!";

                if (opScore >= 5)
                    gameoverText = $"{opName} won the game! Congratulations!";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gameoverText))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(gameoverText);

                    playing = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string opMove = opMoves();
                    Console.WriteLine(playerScore);
                    Console.WriteLine(opScore);
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose your move! Valid moves:\nRock\nPaper\nScissors");
                    string playerMove = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine(namesIndex + " Choosing move...");
                    Console.WriteLine("Your move:  " + playerMove + "\n " + opName + "'s move:  " + opMove);


                    // If player uses paper and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper beats Rock! You gain 1 point!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses paper and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors beat Paper! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses paper and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "paper" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper vs Paper is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Paper beats rock! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        opScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock vs Rock is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }

                    // If player uses rock and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "rock" && opMove == "Scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock beats Scissors! 1 point awarded to player!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses paper
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors beat Paper! 1 point awarded to player!");
                        playerScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses rock
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rock beats Scissors! " + opName + " gains 1 point!");
                        opScore++;
                    }

                    // If player uses scissors and op uses scissors
                    if (playerMove.ToLower() == "scissors" && opMove == "Rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Scissors vs Scissors is a tie! No points awarded!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! It does however solve the problem that I'm facing. I'm starting to believe that it might be a problem on my computer, as it still doesn't break the loop when the player or the AI opponent reaches 5 points.